# Reference the IMG src from a dymanic id and static class selector

Tags: jquery

I use the same classes for my elements, but I change the id.the id is unique

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="" class="wanted" id="'.$status_id[$num].'">
        <img src="/images/wanted.png">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="unwanted" id="'.$status_id[$num].'">
        <img src="/images/unwanted.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to reference the unwanted.png to change it in jquery when the class wanted is clicked.

I use `var x = document.getElementById(id);` to get `.wanted`, but I cannot figure out how to get `.unwanted` without using the `$(this)` reference.

Any help will be super useful.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ -- Use `$('#'+id)` to select an element by id and `$('.wanted')` to select by class-name

Comment: I want to select the set the `img element. How do I use the selector for `$('#'+id+'.unwanted').find("img")[0].setAttribute("src","/images/unwanted.png");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on one of the links, get its sibling:

```
$('.buttons a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var otherLink = $(this).siblings().first();

    // do something with other link
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5G7m/)

Comment: Wow. I wish I knew this call an hour ago. So simple, and I don't have to change my ids to be completely unique despite was everyone else says.

Comment: @michael Yes you have to. Or your code won't be correct and can lead to errors.

Comment: @michael Technically they should still be unique. Many of jQuery's features assume that they are and won't work correctly if they aren't -- it's an html rule. If you want an attribute to be shared by both use `class` instead. An element can have multiple classes, just separate them with a space `class='class1 class2'`.

Comment: I could make the container box the unique id and then the individual links the classes. I would then have to call the parent to get the id and then it might conform, correct?

Answer (score 0):

2 HTML elements shouldn't have the same id.

However, using JQuery you can use not: `$('anyselector:not(.unwanted)')`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I would use the :not selector to reference the .unwanted img on the same id as the .wanted click?

Comment: Ok so, what do you want to do exactly ? Did you put the same ID for the two element ? I'm not sure. But if so, it's not allowed in HTML. However, you can put multiple class names (separated by a space) on one element to group or distinguish them.

Comment: The HTML is at the top of the post. I have the same ID, but the classes are different. Do you have a suggestion on how to modify this so I can reference them properly? Thank you.

Comment: @michael you have missed the whole point about id's and how they should be unique

Comment: 'Unique' means all the ids need to be different, not that they should all be the same...

Comment: You can do `<a href="" class="link wanted" id="first-link">[...]</a>` and then `<a href="" class="link unwanted" id="second-link">[...]</a>` for exemple.

Comment: I see that. I appreciate the feed back. Can you help me fix this code format? I originally planned the ids to be " `"wanted'.$status_id[$num].'"` and `"unwanted'.$status_id[$num].'"` it just did not make sense from calling the ids dynamically.